# if I login a website with facebook account, what can the ower of the website do with my account?

Tags: facebook

I use my facebook account to login in several websites. I am worried that the owners of the website can do something with my accounts. So what can they do? Is there any official document about the issue from facebook?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you connect with a Facebook App, make sure to read what permission it requests. Every additional permission is shown in the authorization popup. Without any additional permission, the only data any App can get is an "App Scoped ID" (only unique in that one App), the name of the user, the locale of the user...

Example response, showing the data from basic permissions:

```
{
  "id": "xxx",
  "first_name": "John",
  "gender": "male",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/xxx/",
  "locale": "en_US",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "timezone": 1,
  "updated_time": "2014-09-06T12:14:41+0000",
  "verified": true
}
```

Since April 2014, Apps need to go through a [review process](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login) on Facebook before they work for any User - so you don´t really need to worry that much about the malicious permissions anymore (publish_actions, for example). Friend permissions are deprecated, Apps can´t get any data from your friends either. Check out the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Also, User Access Tokens are only valid for 60 days max. If you don´t use the App for more than 2 months, it can´t use the Token anymore > no API call possible anymore.

TL;DR: Don´t worry :)

Answer (score 0):

In very simple terms, all you are doing is authenticating against Facebook for the site.

The site will redirect you to Facebook and receive a token back saying you are who you are.

They cannot change/access your account if you are worried about that.

Comment: no, all they get back is a token basically say you are who you say you are, which they match against their records.

Answer (score 0):

Unless given explicit permission to change/access data you need to give it permission (if an app or software uses it to connect youll get a prompt from facebook authenticating you and asking if you accept that app/software to do that). The facebpok API absolutely does not have access to your actual messages between friends.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/quickstart/v2.2

Answer (score 0):

I think sometimes it also depends on the application that you use after fb authentication. All of them do ask you what information you want to share. Some of the mobile applications do require you to share your friends list with them. I haven't come across any apps as of now that needs your posts.